# Redux : New value returned from reducer not updating in State

Tags: reactjs, redux

During initial load, the value returned from reducer is getting updated.
But the subsequent values returned are not getting updated in the state.

Below the reducer code, connectToTradeServer is a function which makes a axios call to another site and gets data.

```
export default (state = [{"_id":"helkjdflj"}], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TRADE_LIST_UPDATED: {
            connectToTradeServer((err, res) => {
               if (err) {
                    return state;
                } else {
                   return res;
               }
            });
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is default case outside switch?

Answer (score 1):

The Redux's reducer by nature is a synchronous function. You have async operation inside. The `return` statement inside `connectToTradeServer` does nothing. I'll suggest to check `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` projects to learn how to handle async operations.

Also in `TRADE_LIST_UPDATED` case you don't `return`. At the end every reducer call ends up returning the initial state.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a newbie to redux, so still a bit confused on how things work. Will check on your suggestions.